# minimal LDAP + user authentication example for *nix

Tags: linux, authentication, setup, ldap

I need to setup a VERY minimal LDAP setup on RHEL / Fedora.

- no need for kerberos
- would like to avoid any DNS server setup
- dont mind if its insecure : it is only for testing.
- all user authentication is done via ldap (no kerberos or /etc/passwd dependency)

I have seen tools such as openldap, but was hoping maybe there is a canned script or something which can yum install the minimal ldap components and enable the necessary modifications to /etc/ files to setup a simple LDAP based user login setup.

Is there any such tool - or are these sorts of things normally done in a heavy-weight context ?

Answer (score 2):

The following works for RHEL 6.x. With Fedora it might work with very little or no changes, though that hasn't been tested.

You need packages nss-pam-ldapd and openldap-clients. Depending on how you like things to work, you might like to add nscd and/or nslcd on top of that as well. Install required packages with `yum -y install nss-pam-ldapd openldap-clients`, the command might also throw in some dependecy packages.

Here is where things may go a little hairy. You may want two things to happen: 1) authenticate users against LDAP and 2) have user entries for passwd/group to flow from LDAP as well. I'm not going to dive into the latter much, because that depends heavily on available LDAP objects and their attributes. The first one is rather straightforward, though.

To authenticate users from LDAP, no matter how they're connecting (that might be a local virtual terminal, SSH connection, a local X11 GDM session or pretty much anything), you use PAM. Files in general are located in `/etc/pam.d` and in RHEL what you really want to fiddle with is `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`. Several other files, like `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` are symbolic links to this file. The file `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` is consulted when a user is authenticated, unless there is a service-specific PAM configuration (e.g. `/etc/pam.d/sshd` which in RHEL systems, though, consults `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` - for details see the file contents).

The following example will let your users authenticate from a local passwd (ie. `/etc/passwd` / `/etc/shadow`) and then from LDAP. The idea is that local passwords override LDAP passwords but you might actually want to it vice versa ie. so that local passwd is the fallback instead of LDAP. What follows should be put into the file `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` (leave the rest of the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` as it is, do not replace whole contents of the file with the following):

```
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass # try a local passwd entry
auth sufficient pam_ldap.so use_first_pass # try a LDAP entry
auth required pam_deny.so # deny access if both passwd and LDAP fails
```

In addition to defining how your users are authenticated, you need to make pam_ldap.so aware of your LDAP server. This is defined in `/etc/ldap.conf`. Manual page for this file is readable with `man pam_ldap` whereas `man ldap.conf` will throw OpenLDAP client library configuration file (`/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`) entry on your terminal. The minimum for your `/etc/ldap.conf` for pam_ldap.so would be something like the following:

```
base <your_base_dn>   # ou=Admin,o=Organization
uri <your_uri>        # ldap://ldapsrv.org.com/
bind_policy soft      # you might want to use hard too, but usually not
ssl off               # you really should be using SSL/TLS
```

Assuming that your LDAP server returns proper posixAccount objects (most likely this is not the case if you're using Microsoft AD which requires extra packages to return posixAccount objects), this should do it and your users should now be able to authenticate themselves against your LDAP server. They still need a local entry in `/etc/passwd` for their UIDs and so on. If you want to get all user information from LDAP instead of just authenticating them against your LDAP server, you have to take a look into nsswitch mechanism (see e.g. `man nss`, `man nsswitch.conf`, `man nslcd.conf`).

Now this is an absolute minimum and not very usable nor secure as it is. You most likely want to use pam_access.so for some whitelisting for users and pam_env.so for usability and so on.

Comment: do the values in <your_base_dn> and <your_uri> have any significance or can they be arbitrary as long as they are consistent

Comment: and a second question : how do you add a couple of mock users into your setup?  Thanks.

Comment: Both strings have a meaning. The first one should form a valid LDAP base DN and the second one is of course the URI of your LDAP server. Adding users would be done in your LDAP server which I don't know anything about and thus can't comment on that.